# Spring Boot not finding internationalization messages files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I have a simple default application with Spring Boot 1.5.9 and thymeleaf and i'm trying to load the messages from internationalized bundles (messages.properties, messages_XX.properties). Spring Boot only works with the messages.properties files, everytime i change the locale to something like "en" it should look for a file named messages_en.properties but it does not find them. What am i doing wrong? i don't get it, i searched the documentation and it should work.

i have the follow folder structure (pretty basic):

src/main/resources/messages.properties

src/main/resources/messages_en.properties

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Created beans in any configuration file

```
   @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("message");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

  @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return sessionLocaleResolver;
    }
```

Comment: It worked! I already had the LocaleResolver bean but i didn't have the MessageSource bean, i thought Spring creates one by default. Why do i need to manually create the MessageSource bean?

Comment: I think this is because, you have not configured spring.messages.basename in application.properties file

Comment: This is weird since it was finding messages.properties but wasn't finding messages_XX.properties